# magento 1.9 sku search not working

Tags: magento-1.9, search

i am trying to search sku but it show product with that character in price also for example my product sku is 123, then it show product with price 2123 like that i do not want this to happen .

also it does not search product by sku means when i search (123 product sku) it does not show respective product.

how can it be fixed , from where can i modify and view what search query id fired based on out search

Comment: in admin catalog-> Manage Attributes . sku searchable YES

Comment: it is already there

Comment: Also check under "Product Information"->General->Visibility that it is set to "Catalog, Search" instead of just "Catalog". If you change settings, you may have to rebuild indexes and refresh cache.

Comment: ok fine it's now but but how can i remove price search issue like when i search 123 , it show product with price 1230 and like that

Comment: in admin catalog-> Manage Attributes . Make price searchable 'No'.

Comment: Use in Quick Search is already set no , also indexing done ,still issue